# What entitles an apk to be like a 'widget'?

Tags: android, android-appwidget

In android developer website, app widget is implemented as a combination of:

1. AppWidgetProviderInfo object
2. AppWidgetProvider class
3. Initial view layout

A typical example of app widget shown in AndroidManifest.xml is:

```
<receiver android:name="ExampleAppWidgetProvider" >   // item '2'
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
               android:resource="@xml/example_appwidget_info" />   // item '1'
</receiver>
```

And item '1' often describe where item '3' is:

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="294dp"
    android:minHeight="72dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="86400000"
    android:previewImage="@drawable/preview"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/example_appwidget"    // item '3'
    android:configure="com.example.android.ExampleAppWidgetConfigure" 
    android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical">
</appwidget-provider>
```

I've seen many app widget examples like this.

However i still don't understand what signature 'AppWidget framework' use to find all app widgets on the phone and put them under '**Widgets**' tab in main menu.

To enable app to be shown under '**All apps**' tab in main menu, you can add below to one of its activity's intent filter.

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

**however, what are the corresponding magic keywords for app widget?** How does launcher recognize an app widget and put it under 'Widgets' tab?

I know it's probably NOT because of the item 1,2,3 signature, 'cause i came across an old app widget that someone else developed, and i can not see the 1,2,3 pattern. And i have no idea how 'AppWidget framework' can figure out it's a app widget.

I list the old app widget's manifest file below, if you can point out where should i look for clues, i'll really appreciate it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.weather">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <application
        android:process="com.example.weather.sinaweather" 
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/widget_weather_icon">

        <provider
            android:name=".provider.WeatherProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.weather" />
        <activity
            android:name=".WeatherDetail"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true">
        </activity>        
        <activity
            android:name=".WeatherDetailActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden|navigation">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".AlertActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
            <intent-filter>
                <!--action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /-->
                <!--category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /-->
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.weather.action.START_WEATHER_SETTINGS" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.weather.action.START_WEATHER_APPLICATION" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".WeatherDisplayCurrentDialog"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.weather.DISPLAY_CURRENT_CONFIGURE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".AddCityActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden|navigation|locale">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.weather.action.START_WEATHER_SETTINGS_INTELNAL" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter> 
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SearchCityActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden|navigation">
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".WeatherService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.weather.INIT_APP" />
                <action android:name="com.example.weather.WEATHER_RETRY" />
                <action android:name="com.example.weather.RESET_AUTO_UPDATE_ALARM" />
                <action android:name="com.example.weather.WEATHER_AUTOUPDATE" />
                <action android:name="com.example.weather.action.NEED_WEATHER_INFO" />
                <action android:name="com.example.weather.action.TOP_CITY_CHANGED" />
                <action android:name="com.example.weather.LOCATION_UPDATE" />          
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <receiver
            android:name=".WeatherReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="com.example.weather.RESTART_SERVICE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Read [this article](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html) for detailed instructions on creating and declaring a widget. What you call the '1-2-3' pattern is required in manifest.